# label width in jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css, jquery-mobile

i am using jquery mobile to build my ui
but the problem is i am not able to adjust the width of my label
can u tell me how to make the width of all my label to 108px

http://jsfiddle.net/GZaqz/

code below

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
<label data-role="none" for="basic">Zip</label>
<input style="width: 280px;" data-role="none" type="text"
    name="name" id="basic" value="">
</div>
```

I am trying to achieve some thing similar to this for all labels with constant width

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's some problem in your markup - the `for` property of the labels is not the same as the name of the input. This prevents jQuery Mobile from properly styling your content. For example, this:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
    <label data-role="none" for="basic">Phone</label>
    <input style="width: 280px;" data-role="none" type="text" name="name" id="basic" value=""  />
</div>
```

Should be changed to this (note the `for` and `name` properties now match):

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
    <label data-role="none" for="basic">Phone</label>
    <input style="width: 280px;" data-role="none" type="text" name="basic" id="basic" value=""  />
</div>
```

Once this is done, jQuery Mobile should make your form work pretty much the way you want.